# Combine cells together with a seperator How to achieve this in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have an Excel having two columns:

```
    Col1   Col2
    A01    Z01
    A02    Z02
    A03    Z03
```

I need some formula so that the values in third column should be:

```
    Col3
    A01 - Z01
    A01 - Z02
    A01 - Z03
    A02 - Z01
    A02 - Z02
    A02 - Z03
    A03 - Z01
    A03 - Z02
    A03 - Z03
```

Please help!

Comment: See the formula answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741469/every-possible-combination-of-the-contents-of-2-columns-in-excel).

Answer (score 2):

**To combine all values in column A with all values in column B in order to get all possible combinations, you can type this formula into column C:**

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($A$1)<COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B),OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-ROW($A$1))/COUNTA(B:B),0)&" - "&OFFSET($B$1,MOD(ROW()-ROW($A$1),COUNTA(B:B)),0),"")
```

The core of this formula are the two `OFFSET` functions. They determine how many rows from `$A$1` or `$B$1` you must go down for each of the combinations (depending on the row number you are in).
The number of rows to go down in `column A` is determined by:

```
(ROW()-ROW($A$1))/COUNTA(B:B)
```

You divide the number of rows (i.e. the distance from `A$1$`) with the number of values in `column B`. Please note, if the result is let’s say 1,67, `OFFSET` will go down 1 cell (it will always round down).

For `column B`, we additionally use the `MOD` function. It indicates the remainder of a division (e.g. 5/3 will be 2).

```
MOD(ROW()-ROW($A$3);COUNTA(B:B))
```

So again, we calculate the row distance from `$A$1`, divide it by the total number of values in `column B` and take the remainder.
Look at the picture for a better illustration.

[image: Concatenate all values in column A with all values in column B in Excel]

The rest is easy: `&” – “&` concatenates the two `OFFSET` results and the `IF` function just checks if all combinations have already been displayed (and eventually displays a blank).

I hope that helps you and you are able the understand the steps in this formula.

Comment: If I do this and drag the column C1, it will result in
    A01 - B01
 A02 - B02
 A03 - B03

Not in the required way.

Comment: @user1326379 Sorry, I did not see recognize that. I will correct my answer.

Comment: @user1326379 I have updated my answer, now it looks much better.