# Create rows from combination of other rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm looking for a way to repeat records/rows based on two different tables, like below:

**TABLE 1:**

```
Col1  Col2
A     101
B     102
C     103
```

**TABLE 2:**

```
Col3
1
2
3
```

**REPEATING RESULTS:**

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
A      101    1
B      102    1
C      103    1 
A      101    2
B      102    2
C      103    2
A      101    3
B      102    3
C      103    3
```

In 'Microsoft Access' or SQL i can do it very quickly, by using SQL select string:

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column1
FROM table1, table2
```

but i'm wondering if there is any way to do it in google sheets with QUERY function etc.

Comment: I know there is already a question similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741469/every-possible-combination-of-the-contents-of-2-columns-in-excel), but there is no answer there about google-sheets and QUERY function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this via a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) created in Google Apps Script. To achieve this, follow these steps:

- In your spreadsheet, select **Tools > Script editor** to open a script bound to your file.
- Copy this function in the script editor, and save the project:

```js
function REPEAT(table1, table2) {
  var output = [];
  output.push([]);
  for (var i = 0; i < table1[0].length; i++) {
    output[0].push(table1[0][i]);
  }    
  for (var i = 0; i < table2[0].length; i++) {
    output[0].push(table2[0][i]);
  } 
  for (var i = 1; i < table2.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < table1.length; j++) {
      output.push([]);
      for (var k = 0; k < table1[j].length; k++) {
        output[output.length - 1].push(table1[j][k]);
      }    
      for (var k = 0; k < table2[i].length; k++) {
        output[output.length - 1].push(table2[i][k]);
      }       
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

- Now, if you go back to your spreadsheet, you can use this function just as you would do with any other function. You just have to provide the appropriate table ranges as parameters, as you can see here:

[image]

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Great answer!! Works great. PS. in this function the first row from tables will be used for headers only.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
=ArrayFormula(sort(split(transpose(split(textjoin(",", 1, split(textjoin(",", 1, A2:A4&"_"&transpose(B2:B4)),",")&"_"&A10:A12), ",")), "_")))
```

Change range to suit.

[image]