# Combining Excel Tables/Ranges Line by Line

Tags: excel, vba

I have two lists. One contains names and the other contains workshop information.

So list one looks like this:

```
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
.
.
Name X
```

This list results from an external query and is formatted as a table. It's content changes from time to time.

The other looks like this and is simply formatted as table (without an underlying query):

```
Workshop 1
Workshop 2
Workshop 3
Workshop 4
```

I'd like to combine these two lists and the result should look like this:

```
Name 1 | Workshop 1
Name 1 | Workshop 2
Name 1 | Workshop 3
Name 1 | Workshop 4
Name 2 | Workshop 1
.
.
.
and so on.
```

So, as you can see, the total number of lines expands four times. Since the first table has already around 400 lines, copy and paste is not an option.

I have no clue to resolve this. All I've found is about JOIN tables, but therefore I need some common columns that I do not have here.

Is there any way to resolve this problem with formulas/Power Queries? Or do I have to use VBA?

Looking forward for some support,

regards
Olaf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741469/every-possible-combination-of-the-contents-of-2-columns-in-excel has both a VBA and formula solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **Power Query** approach.

You have the two tables created on a sheet - one named `NameTable` the other `WorkshopTable`.

Create a connection only query for each table.  I've named these `NameTableQuery` and `WorkshopTableQuery`:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NameTable"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

and

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="WorkshopTable"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Workshop", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Now to create a cartesian product of the two.  Start with a reference to one, then add the other as a new column which you expand:

```
let
    Source = WorkshopTableQuery,
    #"Add Names" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Names", each NameTableQuery),
    #"Expanded Names" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Add Names", "Names", {"Name"}, {"Name"})
in
    #"Expanded Names"
```

You final table will be:

```
| Workshop   | Name   |
|------------|--------|
| Workshop 1 | Name 1 |
| Workshop 1 | Name 2 |
| Workshop 1 | Name 3 |
| Workshop 1 | Name 4 |
| Workshop 1 | Name 5 |
| Workshop 2 | Name 1 |
| Workshop 2 | Name 2 |
| Workshop 2 | Name 3 |
| Workshop 2 | Name 4 |
| Workshop 2 | Name 5 |
```

Comment: Thank you! After some struggle with the third statement I found the trick. That did it!

Comment: No problem - it's a trick I learnt last week when I had the same problem.  Can't remember where I found the answer though.  For the third statement you could leave the `Expanded Names` line out and then use the UI to add it - I had to as couldn't remember why I had to add `{"Name"}, {"Name"}` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. I assumed that names and workshops are in column A in their respective worksheets.

```
Sub JoinData()
  Dim wsName As Wroksheet, wsWorkshop As Worksheet, wsResult As Worksheet
  Set wsName = Worksheets("Worksheet with names")
  Set wsWorkshop = Worksheets("Worksheet with workshops")
  Set wsResult = Worksheets("Worksheet to put results in")

  Dim lastRowName As Long, lastRowWorkshop As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
  Dim columnWithNames As Long, columnWithWorkshops
  ' here you mark, which columns hold the data
  columnWithNames = 1
  columnWithWorkshops = 1
  lastRowName = wsName.Cells(Rows.Count, columnWithNames).End(xlUp).Row
  lastRowWorkshop = wsWorkshop.Cells(Rows.Count, columnWithWorkshops).End(xlUp).Row

  k = 1
  For i = 1 To lastRowName
  For j = 1 To lastRowWorkshop
    wsResult.Cells(k, 1) = lastRowName.Cells(i, columnWithNames)
    wsResult.Cells(k, 2) = lastRowWorkshop.Cells(j, columnWithWorkshops)
    k = k + 1
  Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, try this formula:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROW()-ROW($A$1))/4),)&" | "&INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MOD(ROW()-ROW($A$1),4)+1)
```

[image]

Detailed explanation:

- `INT((ROW()-ROW($A$1))/4)` will add +1 to the ordinal numbers after 4 rows
- `MOD(ROW()-ROW($A$1),4)+1` will generate ordinal numbers 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4 ..
- Finally combining them into offset and index gives the desired result