# Looking for a formula to combine columns in a specific way

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need a formula, not VBA, for column C? See below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJZHc.png)

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | 1 | red 1 |
| yellow | 2 | red 2 |
| blue | 3 | red 3 |
|  | 4 | red 4 |
|  |  | yellow 1 |
|  |  | yellow 2 |
|  |  | yellow 3 |
|  |  | yellow 4 |
|  |  | blue 1 |
|  |  | blue 2 |
|  |  | blue 3 |
|  |  | blue 4 |

Comment: By the way, I think this is a sort of "cartesian product".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try: Using `TOCOL()` & `TOROW()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=TOCOL(A1:A3&" "&TOROW(B1:B4))
```

---