# How to combine every cell in one column with every cell in another?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am trying to combine the strings of every cell in one column to the strings of every cell in another?

Ex:
Column A:

```
A1
A2
```

Column B:

```
B1
B2
B3
```

Desired output in Column 3:

```
A1B1
A1B2
A1B3
A2B1
A2B2
A2B3
```

I tried normal concatenation, but it only joins one cell to everything in the next row

Comment: Here is another link to `Cartesian Product`: **[=TOCOL(A1:A2&TOROW(B1:B3))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76297342/looking-for-a-formula-to-combine-columns-in-a-specific-way)**